# How to get just the first match from grep?

Tags: grep, scripting, rhel, ps

I am writing a script, and I am using this as a variable.

```
RESULT1=`ps -ef | grep -w "PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE"`.
```

What happens is that `ps` is listing two PIDs.

```
[xhobando@noitu TNOITU]$ ps -ef | grep -w "/usr/ud/bin/udt PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE"
phantomxg      7250     1  0 12:15 ?        00:00:01 /usr/ud/bin/udt PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE

phantomxg    17071     1  0 Oct04 ?        00:05:27 /usr/ud/bin/udt PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE
```

what I am trying to achieve here is that the `grep` option only looks for the first PID, and not for both PIDs.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: You should be able to use the `-m` switch to limit the number of matching lines in grep. Alternatively, look at using `pgrep` in place of the `ps | grep` pipeline - it has `--oldest` and `--newest` options

Comment: ...as above, and also have in mind that usually `ps -ef | grep "command"` will also fetch a line for the grep command itself.

Comment: What's special about the "first" PID that makes you want it instead of the other one? Both processes have `PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE` in them, so is it the start time? Elapsed time? Something else?

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller, what makes the first PID special is that, The first PID is located in a different /tdata/PHANTOM, and the second PID is located in /data/MEBA/PHANTOMXG. These are two different PIDS located in two different locations.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` (the implementation found on rhel) built with PCRE support:

```
ps -Ao pid= -o args= |
  grep -Pom1 '^\s*\K\d+(?= \Q/usr/ud/bin/udt PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE\E)'
```

Where

- `-P` switches to `P`erl-like regular expressions (for `\s`, `\K`, `\d`, `(?=...)`, `\Q`, `\E` all perl like extensions).
- `-o` tells `grep` to only output the matched portion
- `-m1` tells `grep` to only output matches for the first matching line.

(all 3 flags happen to be GNU extensions, but GNU `grep` happens to be the `grep` implementation found on your RHEL).

Rather than using `ps -f` which prints a number of fields we don't care about, we select only the ones we need (`pid` and `args`, the `=` suffix is to remove the headers), so we can more easily match on the command line.

Here the regexp looks for a leading (`^`) sequence of 0 or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`\s`) after which we mark the start of the match (`\K`), followed by a sequence of 1 or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), provided they're followed (`(?=...)` look ahead operator, not part of the match) by a space and those arguments we want (quoted with `\Q`...`\E` to make it easier to replace with other arg lists that could contain regexp operators).

Or just use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -f '^/usr/ud/bin/udt PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE' | head -n 1
```

Would return the pid for the first process whose arg list (concatenated with space characters) starts with `/usr/ud/bin/udt PHANTOM PHA-WRM-EXPIRE`.

Note that processes are ordered numerically by pid by default in the output of `ps` or `pgrep`, and pid numbers wrap when they reach their maximum value, so which one you'll get will be more or less random.

You may want to add some `--sort start_time` or `--sort -start_time` to `ps`  for instance to sort by start time  (or add `-o`/`-n` for *oldest*/*newest* to `pgrep` and drop the `| head -n 1`) if you want to get the process that was started earliest/latest, not that it would guarantee that it be the one that *executed `udt`* first/last as processes can and often do run more than one command in their life time.

If, as your comment to your question suggests, you want to select processes based on their current working directory, you could use `zsh` instead and do:

```
pids=(
  /proc/<1->(e[$'[[ $REPLY/cwd -ef /tdata/PHANTOM &&
    $(<$REPLY/cmdline) = /usr/ud/bin/udt\0PHANTOM\0PHA-WRM-EXPIRE\0* ]]']:t)
)
```

Here, looking for processes with `/tdata/PHANTOM` as their working directory and with `/usr/ud/bin/udt`, `PHANTOM` and `PHA-WRM-EXPIRE` as their first 3 arguments.

Beware however that unless your process has superuser privileges, you can only find out the working directory of your own processes.